# Find all the nodes at a level of a given node's level

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

This is an interview Question:
Given a node 'k' of a binary tree, find all its sibling and cousins. There is no `nextPointer` available for the nodes.

Cousins: Nodes at the same level as the given node 'k' excluding the sibling of 'k'

I know the answer could be finding the level at which k lies (1st pass) and then print all the nodes at that level (2nd pass) (by using the level order traversal). However, this would be a 2-pass algorithm. Can anyone propose a one-pass or a more efficient algorithm for it.

Example:

```
      15
     /  \ 
    18   19
   / \   / \
  2   3  4  5
 /\  /  /\
1 6  7  8 9

Input: k=6
Output: 1,7,8,9
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "more efficient"? In terms of time complexity, this algorithm is optimal because it has `O(n)` time complexity(and the output size is `O(n)` in the worst case).

Comment: You could do it in a single level-order traversal by forming a list/set of all the entries at the current level, and looking to see if `k` is among them... Filtering out it's sibling(s) and only reporting cousins might require retaining a little extra metadata, though...

Answer (score 0):

An outline of the algorithm will be to use a modified BFS:

1. Set a queue to empty
2. Set a boolean 'found' to false.
3. Enqueue the root.
4. Enqueue a null placeholder.
5. For each element in the queue until the placeholder, enqueue the children. While enqueueing, if the number matches the input value, set 'found' to true.
6. Move the null placeholder from the front to the back of the queue.
7. If found is false continue to 5.
8. If found is true print the queue with the exclusion of the value.

This will do it in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use BFS to print the tree in level order, then check each level with the given node. The time complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.company;

    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Queue;

    public class NodeByLevel {

        LinkedList<Integer> levelOrderList[];

        NodeByLevel(int size){

            levelOrderList = new LinkedList[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                levelOrderList[i] =  new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }



public void PrintByValue(Node root , int val){

    int valueLevel = 0;
    LinkedList<Node> queue =  new LinkedList<>();
    Node marker =  new Node(00);
    int lev = 1;
    queue.add(root);
    queue.add(marker);

    while (queue.size()!=0){
        Node node = queue.poll();

        if(node == marker){

            if(queue.isEmpty() == true) break;

            queue.add(marker);
            lev=lev+1;

        }else{
            levelOrderList[lev].add(node.Data);

            if(node.Data == val)
                valueLevel = lev;
        }

        if(node.left!=null){
            queue.add(node.left);
        }
        if(node.right!=null){
            queue.add(node.right);
        }


    }

    System.out.println("level order");
    System.out.println(levelOrderList[valueLevel]);

}


        public static void main(String[] args){

            Node root =  new Node(10);

            root.Insert(root , 4);
            root.Insert(root , 11);
            root.Insert(root , 2);
            root.Insert(root , 6);
            root.Insert(root , 1);
            root.Insert(root , 3);
            root.Insert(root , 8);
            root.Insert(root , 11);
            root.Insert(root , 15);



            //Pass size of the tree
            NodeByLevel service =  new NodeByLevel(10);
            //pass root node and value which wants to print level
            service.PrintByValue(root , 2);

        }

    }
```

//Node class

```
public class Node {
    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;
    int Data;

    public Node(int value){
        this.Data = value;
        this.left=null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```